# jInstagram unrecognized Date format

Tags: java, date, format, timestamp

In reference to [jInstagram](https://github.com/sachin-handiekar/jInstagram) library, the method [`MediaFeedData.getCreatedTime()`](https://github.com/sachin-handiekar/jInstagram/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jinstagram/entity/users/feed/MediaFeedData.java) returns a `String` whose format I cannot understand.

Examples of its return value:

- `1445858153`
- `1445858042`
- `1445857646`
- `1445857633`

What date format is this? And how can I cast it into a `java.util.Date` object?

Comment: Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are so called `Timestamps`

You can convert them to a readable date and adjust the format with `SimlpeDateFormat`

```
String stringDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(1445858153);
System.out.println(stringDate);
```

To make a Date object from a timestamp use:

```
  Date date = new Date(1445858153);
  System.out.println(date);
```

Give it a try

Comment: This does not give me a reasonable date. Its in the year 1970, while these timestamps should not be that far back.

Comment: @OmarChehab: There is a "gotcha" in java around the use of Epoch Timestamps. Java uses (UTC) milliseconds for Date.getTime() and System.currentTimeMillis() but most other langs expect/use seconds and the specs for Epoch time define them as seconds too. You can multiply by 1000L to get the millisecond version of a second value.

Answer (score 0):

This is the long representation of Date. You can call new Date(14458581538*1000) to obtain date information from this.

use the below code:

```
long lDate = (long)14458581538*1000;
Date date= new Date(lDate);
System.out.println(date);
```

Comment: This is returning the dates in the year 1970, Instagram was launched 2010. These numbers are retrieved from Instagram, so surely this is not the method

Comment: This doesn't seem logical to be honest. This returns `Sun Dec 14 05:36:14 AST 1969`. The number is retrieved from an instagram post? I am very confused

Comment: You're correct, just cast the value to `(long)` first

Comment: yes the value was actually take as integer type because of which you were getting this issue.